# checking both updated_at and created_at filter with OR condition for product collection

Tags: magento-1.9, products, product-collection, resource-model

Hello Please help me to updated this query to apply updated_at filter too with OR condition.

Here If I want to add 'updated_at' too in the filter with the same condition like 'created_at' then what should I do in below query:

```
 $products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                                    ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array(
                                    'from'     => strtotime('-2 days', time()),
                                    'to'       => time(),
                                    'datetime' => true
                                ))->load();
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

**Try This :-**

```
$fromDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-2 days', time());
$toDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(now()));
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                                    ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array(
                                    'from'     => $fromDate,
                                    'to'       => $toDate,
                                    'datetime' => true,
                                ))->load();
```

Comment: but I also want updated_at in filter with OR condition.

Comment: please explain briefly which you want ??

Comment: I want to get all products which are either created or updated from last two days.